# Chain jQ methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, chaining

If I understand jQuery chaining correctly the first method in the list executes and must complete before the next method executes. As such I have the following

```
$.fn.reportZebraStriper = function(options) { 
    console.log('reportZebraStriper()');
    return true;
}

//onDom ready events
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#oom_display_options select")
      .on("change", function(event){
          $('#OOM_vs_Logged').loadUrl(//ajax method call in the global site.js file//);})
      .reportZebraStriper();


})
```

On initial page load everything executes as expected and my console gets the printout from $.fn.reportZebraStriper(). My issue arises when I make a change in the "oom_display_options" drop down the ajax is fired, the content DIV is reloaded, but the reportZebraStriper() does not fire afterwords.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Edit 1:
Where the loadURL() method definition. It's really just a wrapper for jQ's built in .ajax() method; it does some animation displaying while ajax is executing, etc.

```
$.fn.loadUrl = function(url, dataAjax) {
    var target = this;
    target.addBlockLoadingDiv();

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataAjax,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                target.html(data);
            } else {
                target.text("Unable to display requested data, sorry.");
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            target.html(err.response);
        }
    });
};
```

jQ's load() method appears to call execute the callback method immediately (unless Im doing it wrong); this unfort. is the what we need.

---

Edit 2:
Made a ajax call specific for this logi, when the ajax call's 'complete:' is fired It calls the $().reportZebraStriper() method. Not the resolution I was looking for but it worked.

Comment: what do you mean by "the content DIV is reloaded"? I think it would be useful to provide more details.

Comment: -Body
--content_div

The content div get cleared and re-populated with ajax aquired data

Comment: And is the select inside the content DIV?

Comment: Nope. The dropdown is not inside the DIV that gets reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out JS promise objects is what I wanted. I wait for a promise.success call then run the desired jQ logic that needed to wait for ajax to complete.

Answer (score 0):

try `$("#oom_display_options")` you should not need to add any sort of container to your selector when selecting by an id

Comment: hua? The selection works, calling a method -after- ajax has repopulated the container DIV is the issue. Your answer, it has lost me...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery won't wait for the previous method to execute before firing the next one for ajax calls. Since they're asynchronous, it will fire the ajax and then proceed to the next method in the chain.

If you want to fire a function after an ajax call, use the callback of the method that makes the call. This will look something like `$(selector).load(target_url, callback)`, where `callback` would be replaced by the behavior you want to fire after the ajax is done.

For more information, look at the callback section in the [.load() jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: It is executing the callback before the ajax state returns. Boo :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$.fn.reportZebraStriper = function(options) { 
    console.log('reportZebraStriper()');
    return true;
}

//onDom ready events
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#oom_display_options select")
      .on("change", function(event){
          $('#OOM_vs_Logged').loadUrl(/*ajax method call in the global site.js file*/).then(reportZebraStriper);
      });
});
```

where loadUrl function looks like:

```
function loadUrl() {
    return $.ajax({
                      url: // whatever
    });
}
```

[edit] Usually I  check these on jsfiddle, updated above

Comment: FireBug error:   SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

ions[this.selectedIndex].value);}).then(reportZebraStriper();)

Its pointing to the last ; character.


Removing it gives a reportZebraStriper not defined, though it is as per your Answer.

Comment: Would if help if I said loadURL 'can' taker two parameters but only requires the first one (URL)?

Comment: Yes, you can put any number of parameters in loadURL. However, Can you please explain the last comment? I didn't quite get it's context

Comment: loadURL() is a custom defined method. It is used so we do not have to re-write the jQ $.ajax() method over and over. We pass in the URL (!st param) and optional data (second param). It executes, and (hopefully) returns the data we want.

Comment: Ok, so if you can change loadURL to the way I mentioned your problem will be resolved. Actaully `$.ajax({  ...  })` returns a promise which we can hook into `.then()` and put zebraStriper there.

For more information on this refer to this [link](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

Comment: @Pheagey apparently your error is to think that $.ajax returns the data, while it actually returns a promise.

Comment: syntax error...
If I could figure that out it looks like this will work.

Comment: Rewriting the loadURL function:
`$.fn.loadUrl = function(url, dataAjax) {
    var target = this;
    target.addBlockLoadingDiv();

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataAjax,
};`
And the chain becomes `$('#OOM_vs_Logged').loadUrl(/*ajax*/).then(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                target.html(data);
            } else {
                target.text("Unable to display requested data, sorry.");
            }
            reportZebraStriper();
        };)`

Comment: Ah yes, I realized. Thanks @Christophe

Comment: Copy / Pasted it directly, filled in the ajax call URL and...syntax error.

Comment: ReferenceError: reportZebraStriper is not defined

Comment: hmm.. so you probably want `reportZebraStriper()` to work with `$("#oom_display_options select")` since you made it inside `$.fn` scope. Well, in that case, replace the last line `reportZebraStriper();` with `$("#oom_display_options select").reportZebraStriper()` else move it from `$.fn` scope to `$` scope

Comment: $('#OOM_vs_Logged').loadUrl(/*ajax method call in the global site.js file*/).then($().reportZebraStriper()); 

Should run the striper after the loadUrl() method correct?

Comment: correct. I think the correct syntax is then(function(){$().reportZebraStriper();}) though

Comment: Run striper inside `then` as stated

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
$.fn.reportZebraStriper = function(options) { 
    console.log('reportZebraStriper()');
    return true;
};

//onDom ready events
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#oom_display_options select").on("change", function(event){
          $('#OOM_vs_Logged').load(
                "http://jsbin.com/ujabuf/1/edit",
                $.fn.reportZebraStriper()
          );
    });

});
```

Working example you can see at: http://jsbin.com/ujabuf/1/edit

Comment: loadUrl() in my logic is a user defined jQ method.
What is this load() you have?

Side note: loadUrl() in the question already can accept 2 paramaters.

Comment: .load() wont work. We have logic that executes right before the ajax call (loading animations, etc) that would be easy to change. However it seems the callback is executed even before the ajax data/result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need a primer on Javascript synchrony and asynchrony.

Javascript executes single-threaded and freezes the page while it runs. That means none of the changes you make to the page render until your Javascript is done running, and any events that fire while existing Javascript is running wait until that currently running Javascript finishes. Events might be a click or an AJAX call completing.

jQuery as you noted returns itself at the end of most (but not all) calls (and this isn't terribly well documented). The .on() call you're using to tie to the 'change' event returns the jQuery object, so these are equivalent:

```
$("#oom_display_options select").on("change", function(){})
  .reportZebraStriper();
```

and

```
var oom = $("#oom_display_options select");
oom.on("change", function(){});
oom.reportZebraStriper();
```

So what's actually happening is a jquery object is created that points to all select tags in the #oom_display_options tag. Then the .on() call runs, which assigns an onchange event to all the select tags - the code that will run on each change is in the function passed to the .on('change', ...) call. Finally, reportZebraStriper() is run against the jquery object, which happens to do nothing interesting.

Since you don't have .reportZebraStriper() in the event handler, it's not part of the code that will run when the select box is changed.

It's hard to tell what your call to .loadUrl() does, since that's not a part of base jquery - perhaps you or someone you work with has extended .load().

Comment: .loadUrl() is simply a wrapper method for jQuery's & .ajax(). Unfort we don't use the (simplier) .load() to replace content data (yet).

Thanks for the other information though. Good stuff to know.